# Storing images appropriately

Tags: mysql, node.js

I want to store some images using `mysql` and `nodejs`. I have read that it is not a good idea to store them directly in the database but that I should store the path to the image in the database, and store the image in the filesystem.

Say a user uploads an image, how, exactly, do I store the image in the filesystem?

Comment: You could use multer middleware and it will do it here&amp;#39;s more info. https://github.com/expressjs/multer

Comment: Thanks, but the link is not working

Comment: It depends to some (small) extent on file size. If the files are below, say, 100k, then storing them in the db seems to work pretty well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

:D Other than multer you can also try "express-fileupload" if you're using express.
Adds req.files to your requests ( :D easier to work with imo)

https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-fileupload

https://github.com/richardgirges/express-fileupload/tree/master/example#basic-file-upload

```
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
expressApp.use(fileUpload());
```

then in your routes:

```
app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
console.log(req.files.foo); // the uploaded file object
});
```

I also use "sharp" for resizing images:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/sharp

Example(i've not tested this code just copied and change a bit from a project):

```
expressApp.post('/submit-form',(req,res)=>{
let f = req.files.profileImage;
//its usually a good idea to rename files uploaded to sth unique using DateTime with their original name (or instead of their original file name)
const fileName = (f.name.substring(0, f.name.lastIndexOf('.')) + '-' + Date.now().toString()).replace(' ','');
const fileFormat = f.name.substring(f.name.lastIndexOf('.'), f.name.length);
const filePath = path.resolve('public/media') + '/' + folder + fileName + fileFormat;
f.mv((err)=>{
    if(err)
    {
        console.log('sth went wrong while uploading image!');
        return;
    }
    //HERE STORE filePath to Database or sth:

});
})
```

Comment: Alright, but how do I then continue to store the image?

Comment: Using mv function file is stored in your database after the callback.
You can put your own logic and code after this comment: //HERE STORE filePath to Database or sth:

Comment: Ok I get it now, thx!

Answer (score 1):

Use multer middleware for file upload.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer